# Cannot send email from website - Odoo v9 community

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-9

I have this method on `cashflow_report` model:

```
class cashflow_report(models.Model):
    _name = 'cashflow.report'
    _description = 'Cashflow Report'
    _order = "date asc, id asc"
    @api.one
    def send_mail_function_model(self):
        template_id = self.env.ref('opencloud_cashflows.email_template_loan')
        if template_id:
            template_id.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
        return True
```

Then, my email template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<openerp>
<data noupdate="0">
    <!--Email template -->
    <record id="email_template_loan" model="mail.template">
        <field name="name">Loan - Send by Email</field>
        <field name="email_from"><![CDATA[${object.company_id.name} <${(object.company_id.email or user.email)|safe}>]]></field>
        <field name="email_to">${(object.company_id.loan_email and '%s &lt;%s&gt;' % (object.company_id.name, object.company_id.loan_email) or '')|safe}</field>
        <field name="subject">${object.company_id.name} Pedido de préstamo desde blinking.cl</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_cashflow_report"/>
        <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
        <field name="lang">${object.env.user.lang}</field>
        <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
        <div style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Ubuntu, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-color: #FFF; ">
<center><img src="http://www.blinking.cl/images/blinking-img-redes.jpg"></img></center>
<p>Hola ${object.partner_id.bank},</p>
<br/>
<p>Requerimos la siguiente cantidad como préstamo ${object.field_total},</p>
<br/>
<p>Por favor cualquier duda comuniquese con nuestro teléfono ${object.company_id.phone},</p>
<br/>
<p>Muchas Gracias</p>
        ]]></field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Then this javascript method, the file is called `email.js`:

```
odoo.define('opencloud_cashflows.cashflow_report', function (require) {
"use strict";
var ajax = require('web.ajax');
var core = require('web.core');
var session = require('web.session');
var base = require('web_editor.base');
var _t = core._t;
base.url_translations = '/website/translations';
var _t = core._t;
var Model = require('web.DataModel');
$(document).ready(function(){
    var model = new Model('cashflow_report');
    $('send_mail_function_model').click(function(){

    model.call('send_mail_function_model',[])

    })
});
});
```

SO, from a website page in Odoo I call the file:

```
    <template id="assets_frontend_website_page_cashflows" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="Assets Dashboard Website Page">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/opencloud_cashflows/static/src/js/highcharts.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/opencloud_cashflows/static/src/js/exporting.js"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/opencloud_cashflows/static/src/js/email.js"/>
            <style type="text/css">
                ${demo.css}
            </style> ...
```

Then, on a button I call the function, from javascript, which was originally declared on model file:

```
    <center><input id="send_mail_function_model" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="send_mail_function_model" value="Pedir préstamo al Banco" type="submit" style="background-color:#e67e22;"/></center>
```

I don't know if it's the button type (submit), or there is something missing on email template?

I have the outgoing email configured on Odoo's backend, but every time I click on this button it doesn't send anything.

Also, no traces on command line. Nothing.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Inspecting the button on firefox shows this:

```
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead[Learn More]  es5-shim.min.js:2
warning: Some modules could not be started 
Missing dependencies:    Array [ "web.DataModel" ] 
Rejected modules:        Array [ "website_portal",    "website_forum.website_forum", "website_forum.share", "website_payment.website_payment", "website_sale.website_sale", "website_blog.editor" ] 
Non loaded modules:      Array [ "opencloud_cashflows.cashflow_report" ]
```

Comment: Sometimes emails are sent but they bounce back, that might be the 1 case

Comment: Hi, Amey, thank you, but no, it doesn't send anything, I really don't know what could be the issue

Comment: Is the `send_mail_function_model` method actually invoked? If you put print statements will they be shown? Also, check your browser console for any javascript output

Comment: Hi George, just edited my question, well yes, from the javascript it is invoked, then call it from website button.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can debug in send_mail_function_model func! and try: email_template_obj.send_mail(self._cr, self._uid,template_id, ids[0],True, context=self._context) or self.pool('email.template') instead self.env

Comment: Hi, Thank you, gonna try later, but I think it is not calling anything, I mean, somehow that button doesn't call on anything, not sure about the modifications you are suggesting, need to try them, but I think it's not doing anything on website side, no matter what I do on the js file, gonna try and write back, Thanks.